# How to apply if-else condition on two different rasters to produce another rasters?

Tags: arcpy, con, if-else

I want to create a new raster image which meet certain criteria from two underlying images.

I created a dummy raster with each pixel having value = 1.

Raster values are to be set to 0 if underlying pixel values for Raster_1 is between 100 to 110 and Raster_2 is 60 to 80.

I tried to do it with `con` but it gives a raster with garbage pixel values.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("""Con(("Raster_1.tif" < 1002) & ("Raster_1.tif" > 110) & ("Raster_2.tif" < 62) & ("Raster_2.tif" > 80) ,0)""","RasterOut.tif")
```

I wonder can I do it using something like `if-else' condition as we do in MATLAB for matrix operation

Comment: What about it didn't work?  Did you get errors?  Did it produce something unexpected?  Did it do nothing at all?  Please [edit] your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic can equally be done very easily in model builder as shown below:

[image: Model]

You don't need to do a reclassification the CON tool can achieve this. A CON tool would be set up as shown below:

[image: Con tool parameters]

Answer (score 3):

Use Boolean logic. Reclassify the first raster: 0 for all values in your range and 1 for the rest. Do the same for the second. Then use raster calculator and multiply together and the output will be 0 matching your parameters and 1 for everything else.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/reclassify.htm

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm

Comment: Great, but in `outReclass2 = Reclassify("slope_grd", "Value",                        RemapRange([[0,10,"NODATA"],[10,20,1],[20,30,2],                                    [30,40,3],[40,50,4],[50,60,5],[60,75,6]]))` in while remapping `[10,20,1]` 10 will be values including 10 and 20 will be remapped as 1 or remap will take place excluding 10 or 20 or both.